# Команда pip install не работает (pycharm)

Tags: python, pycharm

```
pip : Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правил
ьность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ pip install beautifulsoup4
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Я пытался установить библиотеку beautifulsoup4 в терминале pycharm, вылезает такая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй не через терминал а через консоль, если не помогло проверь есть, ли pip в path.

Comment: А как вызвать консоль?

Comment: Зажми 'Win' и резко нажми 'R', появится окно 'Выполнить', впиши 'cmd' - и всё это без кавычек.